# Go another page when i click button but don't create activity for every button

Tags: android, android-activity

I don't want to create one activity For each of them.
For example, I have 50 countries name. When I click in each of them show cities of that country and then when I click in each of that cities show information about that city.

Comment: Try using Spinners for city list and dialogs for showing info on city or use startActivityforResult

Comment: you need only one activity, the info that you place in those is consistent to an object-->"Country", so there is no need to define hundred of activities...